# How to create a "pass through" form / file POST to remote server in .NET?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to post a file to a remote server and pass along some hidden values. So within my code I want to create a request to http://www.someotherdomain.com/upload.php and retrieve the xml results from that post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. Some sample code can be found at http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx